# Invalid Argument: Userinterface error with createTemplateFromFile

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, sidebar

I have used `createTemplateFromFile` many time in the past.  It lets me use an include method so that CSS and JavaScript can be broken out into a different file.  But today I can't seem to make it work.  Below is my test code bound to a spreadsheet.  Any ideas why its not working?  I tried another existing spreadsheet with a custom dialog using the technique and it works.

Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu("Test");
  menu.addItem("Test", "test");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function test() {
  try {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Test");
    Logger.log(html);
    // was html.evaluate();
    html = html.evaluate(); // correction
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

HTML_Test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select>
      <option value="Doc1">Document 1</option>
      <option value="Doc2">Document 2</option>
      <option value="Doc3">Document 3</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Log

```
[19-01-24 09:54:51:240 PST] {}
[19-01-24 09:54:51:246 PST] Exception: Invalid argument: userInterface
```

Comment: You need to  create HtmlOutput from template. The evaluate doesn't mutate the htmlTemplate, but returns a HtmlOutput. `var htmlOutput=html.evaluate(); ..showSidebar(htmlOutput);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script - HTML service "createTemplateFromFile" not usable from within App (spreadsheet, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894830/google-apps-script-html-service-createtemplatefromfile-not-usable-from-withi)

Answer (score 8):

I've been tweeking this every which way to figure out why it wouldn't work.  You get blind to a simple solution.  `html = html.evaluate()` works.